# Grep command issue

Tags: linux, unix, grep

How am I supposed to print with one Unix command the names (and only the names) of company JMT? Problems with scandinavian letters? By typing

```
grep JMT url | egrep --only-matching '[^[:digit:]]+'
```

I still have company name and + marks I should get rid of.

I'd be very grateful of your help bacause I am new to this.

```
   [Name]                      [Company]

1. Matti Meikäläinen              TTK              36.9
2. Teemu Aho                      JMT              37.0  +0.1
3. Kaarna Käyrä                   JMT              37.1  +0.1
4. Maija Meheväv                  TTK              37.2  +0.1
5. Giglio Matjusha                JMT              37.3  +0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`awk`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/) rather than `grep`, it's much easier to search for text and print other details from matching lines. For example:

```
% echo '[Name] [Company]

Matti Meikäläinen TTK 36.9
Teemu Aho JMT 37.0 +0.1
Kaarna Käyrä JMT 37.1 +0.1
Maija Meheväv TTK 37.2 +0.1
Giglio Matjusha JMT 37.3 +0.1' | awk '$3 == "JMT" { print $1, $2 }'
Teemu Aho
Kaarna Käyrä
Giglio Matjusha
```

This checks whether the third "word" is "JMT" and if so, prints the first and second words. No regular expressions needed (for this case).

Comment: That works beautifully as long as there are no company names with just one word, or three or more words.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your output as a file (for suppressing odd symbols)

```
$> cat ./text 
[Name] [Company]

Matti Meikäläinen TTK 36.9
Teemu Aho JMT 37.0 +0.1
Kaarna Käyrä JMT 37.1 +0.1
Maija Meheväv TTK 37.2 +0.1
Giglio Matjusha JMT 37.3 +0.1
```

So the solution is

```
$> cat ./text | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching ".*(?=JMT)"
Teemu Aho 
Kaarna Käyrä 
Giglio Matjusha
```

If you wanna get rid of the number in front of name:

```
$> cat ./text | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching "[^0-9]*(?=JMT)"
Teemu Aho 
Kaarna Käyrä 
Giglio Matjusha
```

What are we use here is regexp extension from perl, where from we've got those lookahead operator (there is a nice [link](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html) with some info about it).

Comment: It works perfectly but how am i supposed to get rid of the number in front of the name?

Comment: Add that condition to regexp: `"[^0-9]*(?=JMT)"`

Comment: How does this cat command work? Can I just type

$> cat my url | grep --perl-regexp --only-matching ".*(?=JMT)

?

Comment: Grep can takes input stream and process it (like `echo "ab" | grep -o "a"` returns a). Grep also can takes file as argument. So you should redirect your output (it could be the file output or some command output) to grep wipe `|` .

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-o` flag to grep for printing just the matches (like `--only-matching`), and feeding in the `-P` flag for perl regex:

```
grep -o -P '\b[^\d]+\bJMT\b' <your_file_name>
```

gives:

```
Teemu Aho JMT
Kaarna Käyrä JMT
Giglio Matjusha JMT
```

This does assume "JMT" is the last word in the company name. If not just add a following `[^\d+]\b` to the end (The `\b` ensure that trailing/leading spaces aren't included).